# R shiny, How to use selectInput function well?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have folders(A,B,C) and files(a,b,c). The folders are all in the same directory.

Each folder has all the files.

Example: FolderA has files(A-a,A-b,A-c), FolderB has files(B-a,B-b,B-c) and FolderC has files(C-a,C-b,C-c).

So, I want to show a list of these.

This is the output what I want:

[image]

When I select Folder B, I want to show the file list for Folder B on `(Smaller Category)-selectInput`. And if I press the action button, I want to use the reactive function to process the data for that path(Folder B/CsvFile B-c).

**global.R**

```
getFromGlobalR <- memoise(function(path){
       execution code...
}
```

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("selectInput"),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("larger_category"),
    uiOutput("smaller_category"),
    uiOutput("action_btn")
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
executed_statement <- reactive({
    input$action_btn

    isolate({
        if(input$smaller=="") return()
        getFromGlobalR(input$smaller)
    })
})

output$larger_category <- renderUI({
    selectInput("larger", "select folder", choices =list.dirs(path = "./FolderDir", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE))  
})

output$smaller_category <- renderUI({
    selectInput("smaller", "select files", choices = ?)   
})

output$action_btn <- renderUI({
  actionButton("actionBtn", class="btn-primary", "search")
})
```

I don't know what to put in the `choices` parameter for `output$smaller_category`.

I tried to use `choices=list.files(paste("./",input$larger,sep=""), ".csv")`. But It's not worked.

Also, I don't know if it works fine even if I put the `choices` parameter in `output$smaller_category`.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what do you get? Are you able to populate the the smaller selectInput, but not sure if they belong to the right directory? or are you unable to get it populated by the values in the 1st place?

Comment: The folders are all in the same directory.
I don't know how to populate larger selectInput to smaller selectInput.

Comment: First of all try to print `input$larger` for debugging, I assume this is working. Then why do you paste ".csv", `list.files` should return the names .csv

Comment: When I print `input$larger in server.R.`
I got an error Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: Use browser(), or make sth like `output$d <- renderPrint(input$larger)` in the Server and `verbatimTextOutput("d")` in the UI

Comment: Oh! Thanks.  I printed `input$larger`. The result I selected is good. However, the output is changed to the initial value again.

Comment: If the initial Folder is A, 
`[1] "Folder B" <- It is what I select`
`[1] "Folder A" <- It is changed to the initial value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Debugging**

First of all you need to debug and see your values by using `browser()` or printing the values, for example:

- In the server `output$d <- renderPrint(input$larger)`
- In the ui `verbatimTextOutput("d")`

**Possible Issues**

- `selectInput` defaults to the first value for single-select lists if `selected` is not set.
- If `FolderDir` is reactive, it will have an effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!